# Android ABS shows large ProgressBar

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I use `setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);` in my activity to show a Indertiminate ProgressBar. This shows a large ProgressBar in the ActionBar. I want to use a small progress bar . How can i do this ?

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a style in order to get a small progressbar.

See this link, where explains how to change the Default Indeterminate Progress Size in ActionBarSherlock

> http://thanksmister.com/2012/03/30/change-default-progress-actionbarsherlock/